# Running Service In Second AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, service-reference

I have an object that I am instantiating into its own AppDomain.  The main reason for this is that it calls into code that I don't control (third party dll) and if I need to Abort the thread, I can do it and then destroy the AppDomain just to be sure nothing wonky happens.  This part works fine.

However, this object also has a reference to a ServiceReference that I do control.  Since the service reference is in the object in the second AppDomain, I'm getting a serialization exception because the Service is not marked as Serializable.  The service reference is just a proxy generated for my by Visual Studio and I'm not sure the proper way to resolve this issue.

Is there a different design I should be using, or is there a simple way to run a service from inside a seperate AppDomain?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Can you show some Code sample of your service & the object?

Comment: I'll simplify everything and post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem.  I had my Type marked as [Serializable] instead of deriving it from MarshalByRefObject.  Once I figure this out, everything seemed to start working fine.

However, now that I have a few CPU cycles under my belt using this new model, I'm not happy with it and am looking for another way.  I'll post a seperate "design" question later.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to use something like .Net Remoting for using objects between appdomains.